# Does Tomcat keep redeploying war?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

I have Tomcat8 running and have deployed a app.war file in the webapps directory. My question is, when Tomcat is started up it deploys the app.war file and creates the app folder. If i leave the app.war file in the webapps directory will Tomcat redeploy it every time it is restarted or does it check to see the existing app folder is present?

Comment: The tomcat docs say (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/deployer-howto.html) "Any Context Descriptors will be deployed first.
Exploded web applications not referenced by any Context Descriptor will then be deployed. If they have an associated .WAR file in the appBase and it is newer than the exploded web application, the exploded directory will be removed and the webapp will be redeployed from the .WAR
.WAR files will be deployed" so i'm assuming it should not always redeploy on restart?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question. From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/deployer-howto.html):

> The following deployment sequence will occur on Tomcat startup in that case:
>
> 1. Any Context Descriptors will be deployed first.
> 2. Exploded web applications not referenced by any Context Descriptor will then be deployed. **If they have an associated .WAR file in the appBase and it is newer than the exploded web application, the exploded directory will be removed and the webapp will be redeployed from the .WAR**
> 3. .WAR files will be deployed

So, the answer to your question is that the war is redeployed only if it is newer than the corresponding exploded directory.

Comment: Do you know of a property that might override this behavior?  I've always noticed it works as you describe, but recently in a new deployment the application directory seems to be rebuilt every tomcat restarts, even if the war file doesn't change.